# 3d Textures from Flat texture

Tags: texturing, normals

I would like to use the flat textures on TextureMate in Blender but am not sure how to convert to 3D textures or even if this is possible. Are there any detailed guides on how to do this? I also have CrazyBump but am not familiar with it yet though this should help hopefully with converting those flat images to normal/bump maps.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on exactly that. http://youtu.be/W07H7xeUnGE

Comment: More information on exactly what you want to do might result in a better answer. For example, do you want to use nodes in your material? What are you trying to texture, and how is it going to be used? And probably related questions I've not thought of just yet.

Comment: I think my mistake was assuming that TextureMate would be able to consistently provide textures for my needs. Not all of their images even seem to be seamless. I don't think I can handle the art and time commitment to creating custom textures so anyone know a good repository site?

Comment: @user1894167 See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/599